# How to set origin/HEAD in remote branch

Tags: git

When I clone a repo, for some reason, it automatically goes to Test_Branch.

```
$ git branch -a
* Test_Branch
  remotes/origin/Test_Branch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> Test_Branch
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

I think it is because "remotes/origin/HEAD" points to Test_Branch.

My question is how can I set 'remotes/origin/HEAD' so that i will automatically goes to develop instead of Test_Branch whenever I clone?

Answer (score 0):

To set the default branch when cloning to develop, use

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/develop
```

To clone a repository and checkout a specific branch, use the `-b branchname` flag, e.g.

```
git clone repo.git -b develop
```

sources:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-symbolic-ref.html
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html